# ckeditor cant save with '#' character in color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using Ckeditor in my asp.net mvc application.

The problem is that when I try to save the data in the form, its not saving to database. I think its to do with some special characters used in colour section of html.

Please note that the colour option is important.

If I manually enter in Ckeditor source section:

```
<p><span style=" color: purple;">Out of Stock</span></p>
it takes it and saves as 
<p><span style="color:purple">Out of Stock</span></p>
```

but if I choose color automatically from ckeditor, resulting in

```
<p><span style="color:#000080">Out of Stock</span></p>
```

it doesn't save this record into database. The ckeditor keeps on saving and hangs there saving.

and its not a database problem as this works.

```
UPDATE table
SET out_of_stocktext= '<p><span style="color:#000080">Out of Stock</span></p>'
WHERE redemption_no = 201592;
```

Would you have any idea which section in my application or ckeditor I need to change to handle this. Please note automatic colour selection is necessary.

Comment: maybe i can configure ckeditor so that only about 5 colours show up and use the actual colour names {red, blue, green, black}  ?

Comment: Its using JsonResult to update the fields  public JsonResult UpdateStatus(int id, int status, string stockText, int points)
        {    //update  }

Comment: Oh, I think its to do with passing # as query string  parameter.

Comment: If this is passed as a query string parameter, then it will fail because the `#` character is a fragment identifier - everything after the `#` (including the `#`) is stripped and not sent to the server. You need to post the value.

Comment: You could try to encode the text..

Answer (score 0):

This did it.

```
// Brazil colors only.
    config.colorButton_colors = '00923E,F8C100,28166F';
    //change color codes to names - so that it doesnt create problems while storing the value. # creates problem
    config.colorButton_colors = 'green/00923E,yellow/F8C100,purple/28166F'
```